# In Polymer 1.0 aligning paper-dropdown-menu with paper input

Tags: polymer

I have the following example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html'>
</head>
<body>
    <div style='width:400px'>
        <paper-input label='Input label' class='inputbox'></paper-input>
        <paper-dropdown-menu label='Drop down label'>
            <paper-menu class='dropdown-content'>
                <paper-item>A</paper-item>
                <paper-item>B</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am trying to get the paper-dropdown-menu to behave like the paper-input with respect to width and padding, but I have a hard time getting it aligned with the input. There seems to be some left padding somewhere in the paper-dropdown-menu and I cannot get it to accept filling 100% width like the input does by default. What can I do?

Thanks :-)

Cheers
Franz Thomsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `paper-dropdown-menu`, there's a `paper-menu-button` of which style needs to be updated too.

```
  paper-dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
  }

  paper-dropdown-menu paper-menu-button {
    width: 100%;      
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7HMiAtDnPBdtgARFaibG?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the paper-dropdown-menu on github. You will see that it is built using a couple of other elements like paper-input, paper-item etc. These are the child elements of paper-dropdown-menu.

To access the CSS of these child elements you will need to use "shadow" as these child elements are in the shadow DOM of paper-dropdown-menu.

```
paper-dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
}
paper-dropdown-menu::shadow paper-input{
  width: 300px;
}
paper-dropdown-menu::shadow paper-item{
   width: 300px;
}
```

This will change the width of the dropdown tab and also the width of what actually opens up when you click it.